# Left join and right join together

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables.

Table 1 has StudentName and StudentID
Table 2 has BookName and BookID
Table 3 has StudentID and BookID

I want to retrieve Records in this format

StudentName, BookName

One student may borrow many books.

But I want names of all Students in the Table 1, even if he has not borrowed a book.

I know it is simple, but i simply cannot get it right.

I can only retrieve records of Students who have borrowed.

I would appreciate Advice and suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried already? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: Tip of today: Never, ever do right joins! You can always do a left join instead, just switch tables. Left joins are not that hard to understand as "main table left join optional data", but right joins are "optional data right join main table".

Comment: Try posting your schema definition and the query that you tried, so people can help you. Don't expect to copy paste homework here and get an instant solution

Comment: Dear Mcha, Rich Benner,

This is what I have tried.

'Code'
SELECT Table1.StudentID, Table1.StudentName, Table2.BookName
FROM (Table1 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.StudentID = Table3.StudentID) INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table3.BookID = Table2. BookID;
'code'

I am getting records that match.

But I need all records from Table1 even if there are no matches in Table3.

JSantos,
I'm not expecting what you are thinking. It is just that one gets stuck at silly things and a third person can see it immediately.

Emile De Favas,
Will try out your suggestion and revert on the results..

Answer (score 2):

If you want all students in `table1`, you must begin with that.

```
select studentname 
from   table1;
```

then you want the books borrowed and keep students even if the book list is empty : let's use `left join`.

```
select    table1.studentname, 
          table3.bookid 
from      table1 
left join table3 on table1.studentid=table3.studentid;
```

now you want the name of the book, instead of the `bookid`. `left join` again

```
select    table1.studentname, 
          table2.bookname 
from      table1 
left join table3 on table1.studentid = table3.studentid 
left join table2 on table3.bookid = table2.bookid;
```

Comment: Got a Missing Operator Error (3075).  But sure got me on the right path.  This helped....  
    `SELECT Table1.StudentName, Table2.BookName
    FROM  
    (Table1 LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1. StudentID = Table3.StudentID) </br>    LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table3.BookID = Table2. BookID;`